# Finding a simple cycle that goes through two vertices

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a directed graph $G$ and two vertices $u$ and $w$, how can we find a simple cycle that goes through $u$ and $w$?

One can try putting together paths from $u$ to $w$ and $w$ to $u$ — but these might have edges or nodes in common, even if they are chosen to be shortest paths.

Comment: What are your thoughts? We're not here to solve your exercises for you. Rather, we're here to help you solve them on your own. Therefore we need to know what exactly you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Well, one can try putting together paths from u to w and w to u -- but these might have edges or nodes in common, even if they are chosen to be shortest paths...

Comment: Not reading any particular textbook or learning any concepts DW -- just thought of the question on my own and didn't know how to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decision version of your problem (deciding whether such a cycle exists) is NP-complete. See Proposition 9.2.1(P3) on page 477 (495) in [Digraphs – Theory, Algorithms and Applications](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/books/dbook/main.pdf) by Bang-Jensen and Gutin.

Comment: Thank you! This is so surprising to me. Perhaps this is because I have no background in computer science (I have an undergrad math degree from a couple of decades ago), but still I never would have guessed this problem isn't poly time.

Comment: Note that this problem is not hard in undirected graphs. It can be solved by a DFS.